# get audio file object from amazon s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, mp3, audioformat, eyed3

I want to get audio tags from an audio file. For that, I use eyed3 plugin.

```
import eyed3
mp3_file = "The_File_Path"
audiofile = eyed3.load(mp3_file)
year = audiofile.tag.getBestDate()
```

But I have only the amazon s3 URL of the audio file. How can I get the file object from the s3 URL?

Comment: have you looked in to boto3?

Comment: are you asking how to download a file?..

Comment: @Sayse not to download, want to read the file using eyed3

Comment: @aws_apprentice not yet

Comment: so look in to [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-examples.html) and use that to download and use this other program `eyed3` to read the audio

Comment: @aws_apprentice is there any other method without downloading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `eyed3.load()` command requires a path to a file in the local operating system.

Therefore, you will need to download the file to the local machine before loading it:

```py
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.resource('s3', region='us-west-2')
s3_client.download_file('my-bucket', 'music.mp3', '/tmp/music.mp3')
```